# Nginx rewrite for Apache rewrite rules

Tags: regex, linux, apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

Rewrite rule for Apache .htaccess to be used in Nginx. We are using `try_files` with $is_args$args but after loading first index page properly, it starts throwing 404 page not found error.

.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Nginx Rule

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
```

We also tried if conditions but result is the same.

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
}
```

Comment: Just use the base rule `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php` and parse and interpret the args in the router script.

Comment: @arkascha Using this rule, java script doesn't load and the index page looks untidy, I have tried lot of stuff including the rule you mentioned, then land up with $is_args$args

Comment: Sorry, that is something we obviously cannot say anything about, since you did not share your code with us. You know, we cannot do magic from here. Sorry. If something does not load correctly then you are expected to check your http servers error log files and your browsers development console for errors and hints that will certainly help to solve the issue. But that is something _you_ obviously have to do. How do you expect _we_ should do that for you?

Comment: @arkascha Please refer to this question, I have explained the details in the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273244/nginx-zfs-rewrite-rule-issue